# Can I automatically send emails when checkbox = True?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, email, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm looking for a script that can automatically send emails when a checkbox is True.
This is my example:
[image: several columns, the last of which is a checkbox]

When I check the checkbox at F2, I want to receive an email with the exact contents from A2 to E2, like this:

- Email subject= [Approved] Form
- Email message= contents below
- Timestamp: 01/06/2020 + times
- Machine/Equiment require: PU1602
- Plant to require: RF
- Team to fix: Ele
- Form no: F01

The email address can be set on the script too.

This is [my sample spreadsheet project](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13zHmppF8lLDlkT7dGeBtRicQ3HbIczHWEv7ql4KDPpE/edit#gid=1097862827).

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to send email based on checkbox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58986485/1330560) from StackOverflow.

Comment: @Tedinoz i just go to u link, but what i want is about var message. I want the message send to my email is contents from Col A to Col E, same row with checked box

Answer (score 0):

The following (untested) script is designed to be installed as an installable onEdit script.

It will detect whether:
1 - a checkbox is marked as true, and
2 - the sheet is the form response sheet, and
3 - the checkbox is in Column F

If all of those conditions are met, then an email will be sent.

---

```
function wa14285401(e) {

  // this script is installed as an installable onEdit trigger
  /*
   if the checkbox is ticked, send this email
   Email subject= [Approved] Form
   Email message= contents below
   Timestamp: 01/06/2020 + times
   Machine/Equiment require: PU1602
   Plant to require: RF
   Team to fix: Ele
   Form no: F01
  */

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "May.2020";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // the checkboxes are in column F
  var eCol=6;

  // get the key event obvjects
  var erange = e.range;
  var eRow = erange.rowStart;
  var eCol = erange.columnStart;
  var eSheet = erange.getSheet().getName();
  var eVal = e.value;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The edited sheet is "+eSheet);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The edited row is "+eRow);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The edited Column is "+eCol);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The edited_value = "+eVal)
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); DEBUG

  // apply logic to detect if check box is ticked.
  if (eSheet == sheetname && eCol== eCol && eVal == "TRUE" ){
    // the stars are in alignedment, send the email
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: send the email");

    // get the data column A to column E
    var data = sheet.getRange(eRow, 1, 1, 7).getValues();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range is "+sheet.getRange(eRow, 1, 1, 5).getA1Notation())

    // get the email address
    var emailaddress= sheet.getRange("H2").getValue();
    Logger.log("the email is "+emailaddress);

    // get the message information
    var timestamp = data[0][0];
    var machine = data[0][1];
    var planttorequire = data[0][2];
    var teamtofix = data[0][3];
    var formnum = data[0][4];

    var emailSubject = "[Approved] Form";

    var emailMessage= "Timestamp: "+timestamp+"\n"+
      "Machine/Equiment require: "+machine+"\n"+
      "Plant to require: "+planttorequire+"\n"+
      "Team to fix: "+teamtofix+"\n"+
      "Form no: "+formnum;
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the message is:"+emailMessage);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, emailSubject, emailMessage);

  }else{
    // something doesn't match
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: do not send the email");

  }

}
```